# Would animals really mutate in the post-apocalypse?

Tags: nuclear

So, in an alternate universe, Soviet Union never falls, and in 2068 a nuclear war happened. About 32,000 nukes were detonated in American, Soviet, EU, and Chinese cities. WW3 lasted about 5 hours or so, and hit every major American city. Anyway to the point, in post apocalyptic fiction, the wasteland is often filled with many mutant animals. I was skeptical of this, but I wondered if this could really happen.  I am trying to make my story as realistic as possible so, my question is would animals mutate, or evolve, after the apocalypse?
My question is, in about 20 human generations, would nay animals change or evolve to look different?

Comment: Just to make it clear, I’m asking if animals would mutate as in evolve like the did in nature. Like would some animals grow bigger, change, or would they be the same as now

Comment: Such a "nuclear winter" event would trigger mass extinction (possibly followed by "nuclear summer" since massive amounts of CO2 and methane would be released after death of plant life creating greenhouse conditions). Most nuclear winter scenarios use a fraction of that much firepower since rapid cooling caused by aerosol particulates would basically devastate all agriculture. The equatorial zone between tropics would be most rapidly affected and that contains more than 90% of species. Not going to be many animals anywhere and especially not large predators.

Comment: "20 human generations" is about 500 years, by my reckoning. Does that sound about right to you?

Comment: @F1Krazy - depends on the average age of reproduction. By that score, yes, 500 years would be about right for current averages. But the expectation would be that in a post-apocalyptic world, the social mores that have pushed the average up would be removed and so people would be having babies at a younger age, so I reckon 400 years is probably more accurate. But either way, a few hundred years is not enough to make a noticeable difference to evolution, even in a radiation zone.

Comment: F1Krazy yes, this story takes place 500, more or less years after the first bombs hit

Comment: The exact time is 501 years, though

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simple answer is no, the hordes of mutant animals after nuclear war is just movie BS, just like the space fighters with wings so they can bank in vacuum.

Now there might be an increased rate of mutations, but most mutations are so detrimental that the creature is unlikely to even survive until birth, let alone to maturity.  (It's also hard to distinguish any radiation-caused mutations from ordinary birth defects.)

Animals would continue to evolve, of course, just as they do now, in response to various pressures.  Consider for instance how the coyote has evolved and expanded its range into eastern North America in response to the removal of other predators, becoming distinctly different from the western coyote in the process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_coyote

There's also the possibility of exotic animals escaping from game farms or private menageries and becoming endemic (as the Burmese python has in Florida), so you might have to deal with tigers and such.

Comment: Its worth noting that if the nuclear apocalypse causes species extinctions (whether immediate or through deleterious mutations), it might replicate previous mass extinction events and the subsequent appearance - through selection - of new species arrays. Wouldn't happen overnight though.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I'm thinking of a timescale of a few human generations as per the OP's scenario, where we might see changes like the eastern coyote - itself a result of human-caused (near) extinction of other predators, leaving an open ecological niche.  When you look at changes over a million years or so after a mass extinction, of course much greater changes are possible.  For instance, look at North American megafauna of just 20K years ago vs 200 years ago vs today.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Also banking in a vacuum is for the pilot, not the aerodynamics.  The vector change applies a G-force.  Humans are more tolerant of this force along the axis of our spine, a tilt directs that force.

Comment: @Jammin4CO that's a great point. Though, can't you just bank the pilot seat?

Comment: @John Dvorak: No, banking doesn't make sense.  Basic physics: if you want to change your direction of motion in a vacuum, you would (simplistically) rotate your ship and apply thrust perpendicular to your path.

Comment: @jamesqf Are you saying that planes in space aren't banking _enough_? If so, I agree. But yeah, space planes don't behave the same as airplanes. But, it does make sense to put your bottom rather than your behind in the direction you're thrusting. Note that [x-wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_X-Wing) did get that right to an extent - if you want to change your direction, you roll, then pitch, because they had terrible yaw. You still had an arbitrary max speed, though.

Comment: @John Dvorak: No, I'm saying that vehicles in space don't bank at all.  I have no idea what you mean by "your bottom rather than your behind". and the link doesn't really help.  The point is that in space, you don't have air friction, so things follow Newton's Laws of motion (and there's no max speed other than the speed of light).  For a practical example, look at the Apollo lunar lander: it was "flying" arse-backwards the whole time it was landing, with thrust vector opposing the direction of motion.

Comment: @jamesqf my point is that 1) if you have a VTOL-capable vehicle, its main thruster will be pointing downwards - unless your plane lands butt-first or your thruster can gimbal ninety degrees in one axis (have fun keeping it pointing through the center of mass at the same time), and 2) while making a turn in space, you want that main thruster to point perpendicular to the direction of your motion. That is, you want to roll 90 degrees in before making a horizontal (relative to your previous orientation) turn. In the end, your desired maneuver will look a whole lot like banking.

Comment: @John Dvorak: In space, there is no down.  And no, the motion necessary to change direction won't look the least little bit like banking.  It looks like - and is - a matter of rotating about an axis.

Answer (score 18):

Your best bet will be to give a look at the Chernobyl Zone, the animals and plants at the place have been living in a contaminated zone for many year now.

The result is... anticlimactic. Most mutations are detrimental and some will outright kill the animal before it can be born. You could have a couple of beneficial mutations, but they are rarely as impressive as Hollywood makes them to be.

What you can have is species adapting to fill in new niches, since humans are gone.

Comment: So much to learn from Chernobyl yet we'd apparently just keep is as a fictitious nuclear wasteland (is that propaganda from oil companies?). Recently read that most existing species, plant and animal, have so much genetic redundancy that there has been little effect on Chernobyl's ecosystem and that we've very much exaggerated the danger of nuclear power. This is coming from biologists, not any nuclear power lobby (if any still exists). 
And with humans gone (out of fear, mostly), actually fewer species of animal life because less agriculture (even gardens) and predator control.

Comment: @Hebekiah You may enjoy a [Radioactive Wolves](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/radioactive-wolves-full-episode/7190/) documentary.

Comment: @Hebekiah Maybe it hasn't affected the overall ecosystem much, but that doesn't necessarily mean individual animals aren't suffering from it. (It just means they reproduce fast enough to make up for it). For example, who would notice if half the rodents in the area get cancer at 3/4 of whatever their normal lifespan is?

Comment: Chernobyl is **very** mild compared to what would happen after WWIII.

Comment: Not really, you need to remenber that any area heavily irradiated will have basically no life. So, the areas where animals will thrive will be the fringes of the detonations, places where the radiation is not so extreme.

Comment: @immibis - Did you just make up those numbers? There was a documented 28% increase in various cancer rates that reduced 95% over 30 years. Thyroid cancer (most directly symptomatic) rose from 1 per million to 100 per million. This is nothing like the "half" you give as an example. 0.01% measured vs your number of 50%

Comment: @LorenPechtel Chernobyl is mild, but radiation it's event produced will also remain *much* longer than in case of a WWIII, due to it being a "dirty" explosion. In case of a nuclear warfare scenario, the immediate effects will be far more dramatic, but also farm more "short-lived" in case of the overall radiation. Much bigger long-term impact will come from all the nuclear plants, all the dams etc. that will be left without maintenance.

Comment: @Hebekiah: I also recall an article showing that some of the apparent "not so bad" effects may be illusory. For example, a study of barn swallows around Chernobyl suggested that barn swallows in irradiated areas were disproportionately immigrants to the area, not a self-sustaining population. Irradiated areas tend to also be areas with few or no people, which will promote wildlife. It can be hard to separate that effect from other effects of the radiation itself.

Comment: The most accurate sentence is the last one.  Animals would only really mutate if there was a biological imperative to fill new niches.  They don't mutate for fun, and any serious genetic mutation will probably result in death vs enhanced abilities.

Comment: @Rozenn Keribin - Yes, I read that report too. It did suggest a barn swallow make good radiation canary - at least 40% of them. Other bird species not nearly as affected while some thrive. I was especially shocked by some raptors successfully nesting in the reactor shield itself since they are feeding on all those "mutated animals" and are known to be sensitive to toxins (especially after patent expires). 
It's a rich field of study with some rare variables; that's why sticking to the facts and trying to properly interpret is so much more fun than the overlaid belief system misinformation.

Comment: @Hebekiah Of course I made up the numbers, hence "for example".

Comment: There WAS a discovery made at Chernobyl.  A species of fungus had evolved to use melanin to absorb gamma rays as an energy source, not unlike how plants use chlorophyll to absorb visible light as an energy source.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotrophic_fungus    I think that's probably the most complex form of extant life you can get to thrive inside a heavily radiated environment.

Answer (score 7):

Any animals alive during the nuclear war will get a large dose of radiation. The only physical change is that they get blast injuries, acute radiation poisoning and/or cancer and die (just like humans).

Those which survive might encounter genetic damage. But most of these random mutations will be detrimental. You will see a lot of birth defects in the next generation. There will be lots of still-birth and those which survive will often have disabilities which just decrease their odds of survival and procreation.

There is a small chance that a radiation-induced mutation actually happens to be useful for survival. But only one specimen will have that mutation at first. When it is really that useful, then it might pass that mutation on to its offsprings. So it will take several generations until the animal with the unusual gene becomes a common sight in your world.

And radiation-induced mutation aside, the nuclear war will likely change the environment your animals live in a lot. Food becomes more scarce, but so do predators. Nuclear dust might change the climate. Humans don't affect the environment anymore. Resistance to radiation becomes a major survival factor. Some animal species become extinct, leaving ecologic niches for others to occupy. And these are just the most obvious changes.

When the environment changes, so do the evolutionary pressures. So after a few generations you might see some changes in the animal populations as they become more adapted to their changed environment.

**tl;dr:** If you want to see some interesting new animals, wait at least a few centuries.

Answer (score 4):

Whether animals would evolve after such an extreme event is not known to science.  It's simply something we haven't fully explored.  As Aify links, the  Chernobyl event lead to a great many mutations, may of which are graphically depicted at [Chernobyl guide](https://chernobylguide.com/chernobyl_mutations/) [Warning: disturbing images].  This site shows a great many people and creatures that are very clearly not fit in the evolutionary sense.  But they're not the only creature at Chernobyl.  [Radiotropic Fungi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiotrophic_fungus) have cropped up.  They literally use melanin, the pigment that makes your skin dark and protects you from UV rays, to soak up gamma radiation and convert it into energy.  To this day we are still trying to figure out exactly how the process works.

So we can see examples of both failures of animals due to mutation and success.  As a general rule, the more complex the creature, the harder it is to find beneficial mutations.  Complex creatures like deer and wolves and people tend to have growth patterns that are designed for very benign living conditions compared to your radioactive paradise.  Generally speaking, it doesn't go well for them.  Simple creatures have the advantage of being able to make a few million offspring and just see what happens.  They also tend to have simpler growth patterns, so they are easier to adapt.

But there is an open question, and for that I turn to evolutionary science.  The current understanding of the fossil record suggests evolution operates in a [punctuated equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuated_equilibrium), species remain rather stable until an event causes them to suddenly and dramatically change.  This theory is relatively new, being only perhaps fifty years old.  Scientists are still debating it, but it suggests that life can indeed evolve at a very very rapid rate, when called upon to do so.  Whether a radioactive world is something which can cause such an event is not known, but if there's one thing we should have learned from Ian Malcom, "Nature finds a way."

Comment: This "Chernobyl guide" is misinformation and fun with photoshop. Here's one "worst case" scenario that tracks many species of plants and especially those like carrots that build up heavy metals over time (not very impressive for doomsayers)  https://www.nature.com/articles/srep39282
Or take a read of Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_the_Chernobyl_disaster#cite_note-Weinberg_1001%E2%80%931005-19 
that concludes that there were 28 deaths in short term, 62 over long. That a 7 fold increase in genetic mutations had little actual effect and diminished rapidly over time.

Comment: "This process is relatively new...", I suggest rewording to "This theory ..." - the *process* is probably at least three billion years old. (Life is about 4 billion, but I don't know how stable the first billion was.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I can see how that makes it more clear =)

Answer (score 4):

Radiation is only one side of the coin.

I agree with most of the answers here. You should not expect in a few years a sudden outburst of "super-beasts" with exceptional properties<sup>1</sup> due to the mutation.

That said, a nuclear war and the following climate changes could lead to a mass extinction, leaving lots of ecological niches open for colonization. So:

- Radiation would increase mutations. But as explained in other answers, most of the changes will be negative to the individual. And even positive changes may be a dead end if they are too radical<sup>2</sup>). So, do not expect that after a few years there will appear a sudden outburst of very dangerous beasts just out of mutation.
- Changed ecosystems will make some current species unviable while others will thrive. I think that this would be a more important factor than radiation. It will be a very unstable system (apex predators usually have few babies so malformations due to radioactivity would hurt them more, herbivores will thrive until they overeat because they no longer have predators, then some herbivores may complement their diet with some meat from dead animals...)

What I would expect:

- Short term: massive death of everything, only a few species survive. Very bad time for predators and mammals, which are very energy-intensive, not so bad for small animals/insects.
- Medium term (decades to centuries): plants and herbivores thrive. The overabundance of herbivores leads to defensive strategies for plants (poisonous trees/thorns/etc.) Scavengers also thrive, and some of them develop into carnivores.
- Long term (even with radiation, tens or hundreds of thousands of years): Animals increase in size, specially predators.

Also, expect some mechanism to limit the spread of mutations/malformations. If too many of your offspring is unviable, you lose too many resources on them for the species to survive. So with increased mutation levels there is strong pressure to avoid mutations, either by changes at biological level (multiple DNA copies, mutant eggs killed in uterus) or at behavior level (killing or casting away "defective" offspring).

In any case, we already have a pretty good record of what evolution can lead up to, and radiation will not change that much. Current (and past) animals were already under a lot of pressure to be as effective as they could be<sup>3</sup>, so you can expect the results of evolution (radiation or not) to be in line with it. Maybe you get a vegetarian dog or a venomous rabbit, but you won't get a flying elephant.

---

<sup>1</sup> The issues with some of their variations, like the "scaled up version of a current animal" have been discussed here to death.

<sup>2</sup> So your are ten times bigger than the usual male of your species? Well, good look finding a female that will be able to carry on your offspring, if you have internal fecundation. Unless you are so lucky as to find a partner with a similar mutation, you are the last of your new species.

<sup>3</sup> Although most of us may be not aware of it due to our capacity as a species to wipe out or keep away anything that could be dangerous to us.

Comment: What makes you think that animals will increase in size in the long term? Shuldn't it be more likely that, since at first smaller individuals fare better, due to their lower energy needs, resulting in a smaller general size (within each species) ?

Comment: @Burki What I mean is that very few or no big species will survive and, *when the situation becomes more stable* and there is an increase of biomass/energy production, big species will become viable again and so some of the small species will evolve to bigger versions. Not necessarily bigger than the current day species (or perhaps a little bigger, if man is not around to hunt them).

Comment: @SJuan76 "Lots of ecological niches open for colonization" doesn't compute with mass extinction of both plants, animals, and less diverse weather, more extreme atmospheric conditions. You go on to basically say that, more that new niches themselves will develop followed by opportunism. The reason I point it out is that we keep using that mantra about open niches - despite its contradiction. I appreciate that you suggested prevalence of CO2-philic plant species  dominating; a likely occurrence. Biomass vs species diversity is a good reminder to adjust our mental picture of the aftermath.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a different answer -- yes! But not because of the radiation.

[This experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox) for example showed that, via only selective breeding, evolution can be quite rapid:

> Russian scientists achieved a population of domesticated foxes that are fundamentally different in temperament and behavior from their wild forebears. Some important changes in physiology and morphology became visible, such as mottled or spotted colored fur. Some scientists[citation needed] believe that these changes obtaining from selection for tameness are caused by lower adrenaline production in the new population, causing physiological changes within relatively few generations yielding genetic combinations not present in the original species. This indicates that selection for tameness, e.g. did not flee, produces changes that are related to the emergence of other dog-like traits, e.g. raised tail, coming into heat every six months rather than annually. These seemingly unrelated changes are a result of pleiotropy.[

Note the change in behaviour as well as shape.

So, existing species may change behaviour (dogs, cows, deer become more aggressive -- like aurochs, wild boar, wolves, and so on).

Climate change might also cause cross-breeding (grizzlies mating with polar bears, for example).

And a few hundred years seems to me plenty of time for long-distance migration -- for Siberian tigers to reach Germany, for example.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you should consider, when thinking about the possibility of animals  mutating in case of a WWIII is the timescale. While I see many people here noting Chernobyl and it's effects on the local wildlife, you should note that a meltdown of a nuclear plant is incredibly different from a nuclear bomb explosion. The Chernobyl will be a scar on the planet for the foreseeable millennia, due to most of the radioactive dirt-pile being in place. Nuclear weapons are relatively "clean". As the nuclear material gets separated into smaller chunks, even with the half-life of radiation for the elements staying the same, it will take far less time for most of the material to become harmless.

What you get is those five hours of initial hellfire, couple of days with radioactive fallout contaminating every place it can reach and in a month the survivors will have to battle the lack of food, uncontaminated water and lack of medicine. The chance of nuclear winter is debatable, so it's up to you to decide if you want to include the short-lived radioactive winter.

Most nukes will be targeted at military bases and other strategic locations first, as even in the "doomsday scenario" it makes zero sense to target some remote field in who-knows-where just to kill some animals. As the preferred method to nuke things is airburst (highest area of effect/lowest remaining radiation), most of the damage to outback places will be due to ensuing forest-fires and the like.

The currently-alive generation of living beings might get irradiated, which will most definitely lead to shortening their lifespan and likely negatively influence the next generation, but the most damage in the mid-term will come because radiation weakened the immunity of the organisms, so there will likely be far stronger infection/virulent outbursts than we're used to. Obviously, all of that will lead to massive changes in ecosystems, leading to a mass extinction event and major gaps in ecosystems.

However, where there are gaps, there are also possibilities. The surviving species will have to accommodate to a different world and *that* will lead to mutations and behavioral changes in two-three decades/century time-span. In twenty human generations the world would look incredibly different and the chances are incredibly high that even in three or four generations the humanity would be back as the dominant species, the big difference being that Australia and Oceania/Africa would likely become the cradle of the new civilizations (as you can't farm off the land, whichever country has an easiest access to food, e.g. fish, has the easiest time to bounce back).

As for the nuke count, 15k isn't that much. If the cold war would go as it went and Soviets with USA decided not to decrease nuke amount since 1960's, what the humanity would have to deal with comes closer to 50k - a count far more likely to wreak havoc in remote places than mere 15k.

The Mutually Assured Destruction isn't scary to the top players(USA, Russia, China etc.) because it would wipe out the entire humanity. It's scary that this war will, regardless of the result, make the ruling faction of any given side a loser, as new key players emerge on the ashes of the old world.

Comment: Turco (nuclear winter theorist), et al, have done predictions with as few as 15-25 cities targeted causing major agricultural catastrophe not to mention key distribution/transport centers' affect. Wreaking havoc on most political structure is that easy. The domino effect of collapsing infrastructure, economic and social systems, would 
likely continue for generations.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for a contrarian answer.  The answer is "If you want", because it wasn't just a nuclear war. A Chinese general, cut off from his command structure, and knowing they were lost, decided to use a viral bio-weapon, considering it the only chance of saving Chinese citizens. Because they were a homogenous people, the scientists had engineered the virus so it would not affect Chinese.

But they got it wrong.

In the beginning, the virus made sterile all but a fraction of the world's non-Chinese population. Then it mutated, first infecting animals. While it did not seem to affect the animals' ability to reproduce, it did have other effects. Before long it jumped back to humans, and eventually found its first Chinese victim. But now they were not protected.

Now of course some random virus is extremely unlikely to cause meaningful change in animals, much less *useful* change. But it does give you a way to work around the 500 year time-scale.

You don't even need a nuclear war for this solution as nuclear winter and radiation are pretty rough. You just need an innocent "oops".

This all depends on how "real" this must be.

Comment: Not so hypothetical: Chiang Kai-shek (the anti-communist general, founder/butcher of modern Taiwan) knocked out dikes and dams to slow the advance of Japanese army and caused major flooding that devastated agricultural areas leading to mass starvation of his own people and all the attendant disease and chaos created by the sudden dislocation of millions of people. 4 million died as a direct result within the year while the effects killed double that over time. Remember that an agricultural catastrophe will become an animal catastrophe as starving people devastate any source of nutrition left.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will mutate. After 15,000 nukes on USA only, only bacterias will remain and they mutate already happily. And in the nuclear winter they will have to change to adapt to the low temperatures.

You new generation had forgotten all books about how dangerous the nuclear war really is. Let alone modern politicians.

Comment: The nukes didn’t all hit America, Gangus, it hit other places to like the EU, Soviet Union,Asia

Comment: OK, ok. Don't forget, that nobody uses nukes for far rockets, h-bombs only. 15000 is much more than enough for all animals. Any one of them gives MUCH more radioactive dirt than one Chernobyl. Radius of full destroying of a 5Mt (medium) h-bomb is 70 km. Even India-Pakistan A-war would kill more than one billion of people. And USA/Russia have thousand times more and more effective bombs. Read the last Putin speech and be afraid of these idiots.

Comment: Make a "small", regional A-war. Then the "normal" apocalypsis picture is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Animals and plants mutate all the time, at a slow rate.  You and everyone else are mutants, since each and everyone of your genes has been mutated as humans evolved.  So radioactivity from a nuclear war might cause a slightly higher mutation rate in animal and plant species. Since most mutations are damaging, most mutated animals and plants would die fast and mutations would not accumulate very fast.

So people would notice a lot of plants and animal species going extinct from the effects of the nuclear war, but probably wouldn't notice an increase in mutations despite expecting to see it.

Answer (score 0):

For fast reproducing animals like mice or insects you should see mutations after a few decades as radiation will increase mutation rates in case they survived the radioactive blast and begin to populate the contaminated lands. Slow reproducing animals will take way longer and get cancer in the process. Some kinds of animals will not be able to survive afterwards due to radiation, loss of habitat and food aswell as change in climate. This will cause the ecosystem to change a lot.

Comment: Gimli, that sounds like common sense but not true. Even tiny-lived fruit flies could only be selected for few characteristics and those differences evaporate over generations or die out. Rodents and especially insects have incredibly long lineage and genetic redundancy and plasticity (self-correcting). Even behaviorally they are self correcting as they'll kill off anti-social freaks. Physical mutation must be matched by changes in sexual selection, not a common occurrence, to pass along mutations even if they are inheritable (many are not compatible with the rest of the genome).

Answer (score -2):

**Where are the monsters?**
Original stories on mutations were written when atomic/nuclear technology was new and there was no data, only fears. Since then we've had most of a century to study effects and to realize that the Earth and Sun have been emitting radiation all along and animals and plants have been dealing with it for billions of years. Species we have today are already, in part, the result of radiation. Natural selection will be the same force after the apocalypse as it has been all along.

Nothing new here but want to emphasize that even writing fiction about false mutation is quite irresponsible. Read [Wikipedia on Chernobyl effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_the_Chernobyl_disaster#cite_note-Weinberg_1001%E2%80%931005-19). 
Studies do say that a meltdown is not equivalent to a bunch of bombs going off; those have much wider spread contamination so immediate effects would be significantly greater while long term effects are less.
But genetic resilience, or plasticity, has proven greater than nuclear radiation effects.

And if it was plausible, mutations over generations adding up to monsters, where are they?  There's been bombs and meltdowns wind carried contamination from Japan all the way to Oregon and where are the monsters? Contamination from those and A bomb testing in the Pacific along with nuclear powered ships and who knows how many leaks, later high yield multi warhead testing... and so **where are the 3 tailed whales with giant fangs?**

I say again it's irresponsible to proliferate such misinformation while the known, documented negative health effects of current energy productions, chemical waste, and "conventional" weapons manufacture and use are contaminating our environment and destroying lives (and those to come) at a terrible rate that all nuclear power and weapons use hasn't come near.
Expanded use of nuclear energy is clearly most likely in the future and by non-fear based studies (and not those of oil company propaganda) much safer. We need to continue research and not encourage misinformation and deliberate bigotry. Authors that continue to do so profit from preying upon reinforcing ignorance.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes in that with 75 years of nuclear pollution there has been no evidence of mutant animals strains developed. 
Zero examples of areas "filled with many mutant animals" which the OP asked. It also directly answers the OP's skepticism of the veracity of post-apocalyptic authors in general in presenting such scenarios.